# Append class instance to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, append, instance

I have created an instance on an object

```
for row in csv_reader:
    temp_case = test_case.TestCase 
    temp_case.file = row[1].strip()
    ...
    test_cases.append(temp_case)
    print(test_cases[0].file)
```

As you can see, I am appending the instances to a list that I can iterate on in other modules and I am checking what it the first item on the list.

... And I am getting for every iteration a different name, but expecting it to be the same:

```
test1.py
test2.py
test3.py
```

BTW, the entire list is of the same instance...

```
print(test_cases[0].file)
print(test_cases[1].file)
print(test_cases[2].file)
```

Result with:

```
test3.py
test3.py
test3.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the following solves the issue:

`temp_case = test_case.TestCase()`